# How to write a FireFox UI-less addon without using XUL files

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, xul

I want to write a FireFox extension which simply loads `myJavaScript.js` if the user navigates to `www.myExampleWebsite.com`. Futhermore this page then detects that the plugin is installed and interacts with it (but this is not part of the question).
I've heard of a possibility by creating an overlay (XUL), which does then define a script-tag  with `src="myJavaScript.js"`. In this file I check with progress listeners for the current URL. 
But this way feels kind of awkward.

My Question is now:
How can I write a native (no special magic SDK) FF plugin without the need for defining a XUL file, but loading a JS file directly if the user navigates to a certain page (owned by me).

In chrome extensions such JS files can be defined directly in the manifest file by using the `content_scripts` key and the `matches` array like:

```
...

"content_scripts":
[{
    "matches": ["https://*.myExampleWebsite.com/*"],
    "js": ["myJavaScript.js"],
    "run_at": "document_idle"
}]

...
```

There must be an equivalent in FF for this.
I searched and googled for 3 hours without any success.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called bootstrap addon.
Search my _ff-addon-template files at my gists on github:

https://gist.github.com/search?q=%40Noitidart+addon

You'll probably be interested in:
_ff-addon-template-BootstrapWatchHostEventListenerInjectFiles.xpi

which watches sites load then do stuff with them on load. basic bootstrap skeleton:
https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9025999

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, while it's not as comfortable as developing chrome extensions.
Now with the power of externally_connectable chrome extensions it's possible to develop extensions for FF and Chrome similarly.